# CSS files just stopped loading // MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: css, frontend, loading

Hello I am new with magento and ran into a issue that has caused a huge headache this morning. I updated a phtml file the same way I have previously but this time I got back this error and now none of the css loads on the front or backend.
[image]

I have flushed the cache and ran my usuall commands that i do

```
m -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

$ php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and still nothing
I have added this to my htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 </IfModule>
```

still does not fix the issue

so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when your CSS is returning a 404 error, it means the browser is expecting CSS but has received text or HTML (the 404 error).

So you need to figure out why your CSS is missing, have you fully recompiled your frontend and cleared cache? If the CSS is still not rendering there could be an error preventing it from being compiled. It's hard to say without seeing your environment.

Comment: Yes fully recompiled and cleared cache its just odd because I have done this hundreds of times and this is the first time I have ran into this issue

Comment: If you made any LESS changes or pulled a branch before this happened have you tried reverting to see if that helps? Just in case there is some invalid LESS that is preventing it from compiling.

Comment: nope did no changes made 1 change to one file and then reverted back and that still didnt fix it